# New email filter option: questions unanswered for __ hours/days

Tags: feature-request, email

I'd like an option in email filters to specify `unanswered for __ hours/days`. Currently I get email about questions which are already answered by the time I look at them. So I'm never able to help on these questions. I'd like to only get email about recent questions that have been sitting around a while with no answers coming. Then I can try to help those who have been left out so far.

(A similar post here on meta does mention "unanswered questions in email filters", but it's been idle almost a year, so I'm posting this separately.)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the similar post that you mention, please?